# Get IP address of all devices connected on the same network in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

How do I get all the IP addresses with device's name that are connected on the same network? So far I have only seen getting local IP address of one's device.

Comment: you need to scan your network

Comment: See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889483/How-to-List-all-devices-info-on-your-WLAN-router)

Answer (score 0):

if you have the device name you can use this...

```
 IPAddress[] IpInHostAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("PCNAME");
 strIpAddress = IpInHostAddress[0].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you. It does work when you add the device's name. What about getting all the IP Addresses with each of their device's names?

Comment: ahh, sorry miss read your question, the morning coffee hasn't kicked in yet. that would involve pinging your ip range, see Cid's comment on you question. the link he added is a good example.